# calculating absenteeism per interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

Dears,
i worked on a new task to calculate the scheduled & abs% per interval, so i make this sheet by query and I'm asking if there something easier than what i create or not
i need to see the same data in the highlighted columns with purple to be generated automatically in the pivot table as i did it by equations
i need the the pivot sum the scheduled agents per interval and minus the scheduled agents if we the time exceeded 9 hours
for more details please check the below hyperlink.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZyhXRLXKnXJsogcGp_Rc1iJswdCoE4Xk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114987741753402000397&rtpof=true&sd=true

[image]